# Sonar without pom?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm messing around with Sonar, there are a limited amount of tutorials and guides on how to get sonar up and running without a pom.xml.

When I use Maven it's über simple, 2 commands and you're up and running!

But let's play with the thought that you want to use Sonar on a project that doesn't use maven, or pom.xml-files for that reason.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not obliged to use Maven if you want to run Sonar analyses. You can also use Ant ([see doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task)) or simply the Java Runner ([see doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+a+simple+Java+Runner)).

The Java Runner is really the simplest way, and this is actually the preferred way when analysing applications built with other languages than Java (for instance C#, PHP, Groovy, Python, Cobol, C/C++, ...)

The main advantage of using Maven for Java projects is that it compiles the project and runs the unit tests for you.

Using Ant can certainly be a bit more complex, however we provide [sample applications](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects) that you can use to get started.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'll have a detailed look!

Comment: Gradle + Sonar = super simple! Great sample applications!

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried it personally, I think you certainly can. See this link http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task+1.0

But be prepared to spend some time to get it working since it will not be as simple as mvn sonar:sonar

Comment: Cool! Thanks! I had a look at similar pages but I didn't manage to find anything as good as this! I'll give it a shot!